# How to remove isAdvertisingTrackingEnabled In Unity

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

We have App in ios. It was developed in unity. Yesterday  apple informed that our app has been rejected  because we have been used  advertising in your app. But we did not used any advertisements in our app. This is the screen shot.
[image]

we have been searching in google. but  we have not found any solutions. So any idea how to remove the Isadvertisingtrackingenabled in unity.

Comment: do you have the unity ads package installed

Comment: @bugfinder no i dont  have unity ads package..

Comment: Well, it seems to think you have either ads or analytics packages installed, please show what packages you have

Comment: @karthikkeyan Have you seen [this](https://forum.unity.com/threads/ios-advertising-identifier-rejection-faq.226187/page-5)?

Comment: @bugfinder thanks for your post.. I  think this is the post i  needed this...  I will try and update soon .

Comment: @bugfinder i have used the above post. But  it is not working.i  have followed the method mentioned in that post. But the app has rejected. Any solution for this..

Comment: Please show what packages are installed in package manager

Comment: @bugfinder and trojanfoe thanks for your help. My App got approved.Actually In Package manager Both Analytics and Ads package are  enabled. I removed it and also i have followed the  forum u have mentioned.Now my app got approved. Thanks for your help. Soon i will post the  steps i followed in answer section.

Answer (score 1):

**strong text**Those who have received the above error. I have followed the below steps and our app got approved.

The answer is taken from this forum
https://forum.unity.com/threads/important-changes-for-ios-kids-apps-action-needed-by-developers.838939/.

all the credit goes to that person only. I am just posting  for information purpose only.

To make the manual fix, please follow the instructions below:

Open the file DeviceSettings.mm within your Xcode project.

Find and remove the line #include 
Find and completely remove the function “QueryASIdentifierManager”

Find the function “UnityAdvertisingIdentifier” and replace it with:

```
extern "C" const char* UnityAdvertisingIdentifier()

{



 return NULL;



}
```

UnityAdvertisingTrackingEnabled()

find the unityadvertisingtrackingenabled and  replace the code.

```
extern "C" int UnityAdvertisingTrackingEnabled()

{



return 0;



}
```

**NOTE:
I**n Package manager . Unity Ads and Unity Analytics are enabled as default. So kindly disable the both. and then following the above steps. it will works fine for me.

after following the above steps mentioned by this above forum . you will receive one error. So to avoid the error.Kindly add

**SystemConfiguration.framework.**

in xcode FrameWork Path.

Then the error will solved and your app also got approved.

if you some one need any assistance i am ready to help you.